# Evaluating Scala with twitter Eval and Scala notebook

Tags: scala, twitter

I've been using twitter Eval function to compile Scala functions. But would prefer to evaluate the function as being provided at project scala-notebook (https://github.com/Bridgewater/scala-notebook)

Is scala-notebook hooking up to the internal repl of machine its running on  ?

How is it different to twitter Eval library (https://twitter.github.io/util/docs/index.html#com.twitter.util.Eval) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both [scala-notebook](https://github.com/Bridgewater/scala-notebook) and [twitter-eval](https://github.com/twitter/util/tree/develop/util-eval) use the [scala-compiler](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler) tool under the hood to compile and interpret the text as scala code. So, technically there is no difference between those two with regard to how they compile the source code.

Just to shed some light on how they both do that, check out the below files:

scala-notebook: https://github.com/Bridgewater/scala-notebook/blob/master/kernel/src/main/scala/com/bwater/notebook/kernel/Repl.scala

twitter-eval: https://github.com/twitter/util/blob/develop/util-eval/src/main/scala/com/twitter/util/Eval.scala

As you can see, both of the use the scala-compiler. The compiler classes and utilities are located in the package '**scala.tools**'